# Conditional Replacement in Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

This Regex `([a-zA-Z0-9]?(?:http[s]?://)?(?:(?:\w+)\.)(?:\S+)(?:\.(?:\w+))+?)` successfully finds any occurances of `http://www.msn.com` or `www.msn.com` or `msdn.microsoft.com` or `http://msdn.microsoft.com` inside of a string. However, there are two replace algorithms that I need to use, this one `<a href=\"$1\" target=\"_blank\" onclick=\"preventDualEditing(event)\">$1</a>` and this one `<a href=\"http://$1\" target=\"_blank\" onclick=\"preventDualEditing(event)\">$1</a>`. **Note the difference is that one prefixes the string with an `http://` which is necessary for the links like `www.msn.com`.**

But, what's happening is the loop that I use the replace statements in is messing things up because if it's trying to replace the `www.msn.com` the first occurance found is `http://www.msn.com` and so it replaces it multiple times - once when it finds the link with an `http://` already and once when it find `www.msn.com`.

Is there a way for me to have a one pass replacement that would conditionally add the `http://` to the string if necessary?

Comment: what does the first [a-zA-Z0-9]? do for you? when would you need to capture something in front of an "http://"?  Can you just capture everything after the "http://" and then always replace it with <a href=\"http://$1\"?

Comment: What that was able to do is ensure I don't for example pickup the parenthesis in this string `(www.msn.com)` - I just pickup the link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with this:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9]?http[s]?://)?((?:(?:\w+)\.)(?:\S+)(?:\.(?:\w+))+?)
```

and use `$2` instead of `$1`

Comment: If I could upvote you 1000 times I would - great idea my friend!